# Как прочитать локальный JSON-файл?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

В Visual Studio создан пустой проект *Web Application*.

[image: проект]

Необходимо прочитать локальный JSON-файл *myData.json*.

Осуществить чтение пробовал так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>1</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn").click(function() {
                //1 способ - не работает.
                $.getJSON("Storage/myData.json", function(data) {
                    alert(data.name);
                });                
                //2 способ - не работает.
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Storage/myData.json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data.name);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert(data.status); // Ошибка 404
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Структура JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Вася"
}
```

Как прочитать файл?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что-то я поспешил с вопросом. Проблему решил путем конфигурации web.config.

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>

// Добавил
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Данные из файла получаю так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $.getJSON("Storage/myData.json", function(data) {
                alert(data.name);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

P.S. Небольшое дополнение. Способ, который представлен выше работает, но если Вы вдруг захотите вернуть прочитанные данные, то можете столкнуться с проблемой (возвращаемый результат будет `undefined`).

Решается проблема следующим образом:

```
function getJsonData(){
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        url: "Storage/myData.json",
        async: false});

    return $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

Может кому-то поможет.